# What is best way to implement i18n / l10n for travel site using Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, translation

I'm developing travel destination listing engine with Rails3. 
Main feature will be listing rooms and location available for booking.

I'm wondering what would be best approach for internalization of my app, since I need descriptions, urls and UI in couple languages. I know than Rails have good i18n built in, but what approach would you recommend for translating contents into multiple languages? Should I go with  [Globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) or something different?

Later, there would be probably also booking engine involved. But not for now.

Comment: perhaps this presentation from Twitter from Railsconf on I18n your app would be helpful http://www.confreaks.com/videos/855-railsconf2012-i18n-on-rails-a-twitter-approach

Comment: Well, I'd be happy to use built-in rails i18n for translating UI, but my worries are models, especially for places, photos descriptions and routing which I need really to be easily translatable because I need them for SEO requirements

Comment: I get you. just thought it might be helpful to share. Well I use Mongoid which comes with it's own localize feature http://two.mongoid.org/docs/documents/localized.html. it works pretty similar to Globalize3, and the gem seems well maintained. With Mongoid this same concept is working perfect for me.

Comment: I'm not yet tied to mysql, so maybe I consider going with mongodb and mongoid. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't suggesting Mongodb is the best option, but was merely comparing the implementation of localizing the model attributes. MongoDB is cool and I love it, but it's definitely not for everything, and you will lose support from so many gems. Watch this demo on mongoid if you like, will help get an idea https://vimeo.com/9864311